# Does anyone know how to report on the correct use of authorizeModel?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am following the CakePHP() book and as I understand it I should put

```php
    $this->Authorization->authorizeModel(‘index’, ‘add’);
```

in `AppController` for automatic authorization of actions, but it is not working nor checking the policies of these actions.

For example: When I try to access /users/add I get the message

> Policy for App\Model\Table\UsersTable has not been defined.

but they are there, and if I take the 'authorizeModel' line it works

Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Comment: "_[...] but they are there [...]_". They are where, and look like what exactly?

Comment: oh you showed the way!
I had created policies only for Entity and not for the Model.
Now it's clear, 
thank you very much @ndm